# MySQL - Count Number of Unique Values with Unique Text

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the count of distinct text with unique entries

This code query will give me the number of distinct queries in the database but don't know how to do it with unique text as well:

```
select count(distinct(query)from tweets
```

Desired Result:

```
Query | Count
-------------
Dog   | 5
Cat   | 2
Melon | 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
select query, count(*)
from tweets
group by query;
```

Note this assumes that what you are calling "text" is really just a `varchar()`.

Comment: Perfect, only getting back into these queries! Cheers!